# How to put a link in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have this HTML:

```
   <article id="1919">
          <div class="entry-content clearfix">
               <div></div>
                <div></div>
          </div>
        </article>
     <article id="1910">
          <div class="entry-content clearfix">
               <div></div>
                <div></div>
          </div>
        </article>
```

I need to put a link in div with class "entry-content clearfix" for all articles

So can I do it JavaScript:

```
 //take all div with these class value
    var eventi_programma=document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content');
   //for to read these elements
    for(var i=0;i<eventi_programma.length;i++){        
    var link="http://www.google.it";//(LINK EXAMPLE);        
    eventi_programma[i].parentElement.innerHTML='<a href="'+link+'" ><div class="entry-content clearfix">'+eventi_programma[i].outerHTML+'</div></a>';        
    }
```

But my code doesn't work.

Comment: _"But my code doesn't work"_ why not? What do you mean by _doesn't work_?

Comment: can you use jquery?

Comment: Doesn't put link in up the div because I would put link

Comment: @Traver no sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function (){

    var eventi_programma=document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content');
   //for to read these elements
    for(var i=0;i<eventi_programma.length;i++){        
    var link="http://www.google.it";//(LINK EXAMPLE);        
    eventi_programma[i].parentElement.innerHTML='<a href="'+link+'" ><div class="entry-content clearfix"> THIS IS A LINK </div></a>';        
    }
})();
```

It didn't work because you are putting `eventi_programma[i].outerHTML` as text of the link. As your for loop is based on `.entry-content` class it basicly creates a never ending for loop since you keep creating new divs with that classname. So instead of putting `outerHTML` put some other text.

Comment: @user501477 how can I put in div class="entry-content clearfix" the all html about this div?

Comment: @lupa what do you mean? you want to put that class in what div? around the <a> element?

Comment: your solution is not complete. Look your code: <div class="entry-content clearfix"> THIS IS A LINK </div>  where you write "this is a link" I need to pur the all HTML that the div class="entry-content clearfix ". The error is here because I use outerHTML. I need to create this <a><div class="entry-content clearfix">CODE HTML FROM DIV</div></a>

Comment: @user501477 look my code html:  <div class="entry-content clearfix">
               <div>...</div>
                <div>...</div>
          </div> the element div with calss "entry-content" has htm div itself and you can't use a string "THIS IS A LINK" like put you!

Comment: @lupa Doesn't David answer your question then? I'm sorry but you're very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `entry-content` class has only one in every article tag ! So I retrieve all article and added then replace it.

```
var eventi_programma = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
//for to read these elements
for(var i=0;i<eventi_programma.length;i++){
    var link="http://www.google.it";//(LINK EXAMPLE);
    org_html = eventi_programma[i].innerHTML;
    new_html = "<a href='"+link+"'>" + org_html + "</a>";
    eventi_programma[i].innerHTML = new_html;    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//take all div with these class value
var eventi_programma = $('div.entry-content');

//for to read these elements

for (var i = 0; i < eventi_programma.length; i++) {

    var link = "http://www.google.it";//(LINK EXAMPLE);        
    var temp = eventi_programma[i];
    $(temp).parent('article').html('<a href="' + link + '" ><div class="entry-content clearfix"></div></a>')
}
```

try it...

Comment: The OP stated in the comments that jquery is not an option.

Comment: I didn't get you... describe properly

Comment: @neeraj sorry but I can't use jquery! :(

Comment: Not being able to understand my comment is not me describing it improperly